# В программе на PySimpleGUI, запущенной на windows7, не отображаются некоторые символы юникода

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, unicode, pysimplegui

Сделал программку на python + PySimpleGUI, на кнопки повесил красивые символы из таблицы юникода.

```
sym_fold = chr(128194)
sym_ques = chr(10067)
sym_disk = chr(128190)
```

Сделал экзэшник.
Запускаю на windows 10 - всё супер

Запускаю на windows 7 - вместо "дискетки" и "папки" квадраты

Вообще не шарю за эти юникоды, подскажите плз есть ли  способ сохранить красивые кнопки на win7 и как это сделать?

см скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, видимо, на Win7 нет шрифта с этими символами или что-то в этом роде. Поразбирайтесь насчёт шрифтов какие у вас там используются в PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Спасибо, и действительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вдруг найдётся еще один человек с подобной проблемной, то что бы win7 видела редкие символы надо указать шрифт "'Segoe UI Symbol'"

```
font=('Segoe UI Symbol', 10)
```